# How to make part of rigged mesh stationary?

Tags: mesh, rigging, weight-painting

How can I make a few specific vertices stay in place and not be affected by the rigging? I've messed around with weight painting and no matter how blue I make it for all the bones it still moves. It actually moves even more when I make it bluer which doesn't make sense to me. Thanks for your time. 
I've uploaded my file so you can see what I'm working with. I need the base of the tentacle to stay put. Just the first layer of vertices that are moving a little bit.

I'm using Blender 2.8

[image]

Comment: Hello! You can upload blend files here: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ Just copy and paste the given code into your question.

Comment: With weight paint it's definitely worth a look at the actual verts. in the group (as in select the group in edit mode and see if there's verts. in the group where the weight map looks fully blue). Just had this issue myself! If you use any sort of soft falloff painting weights you can still gets 'fully blue' looking verts. that still have a non-zero a weight value.

Comment: Do you have any reference vidoes I can watch to show how to look at the verts and see where the soft falloff option is? Thanks MarkS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can read in edit mode, your base vertices do have some weight relatively to many bones, so of course they are moving.

If you want them to stay still, select all of them and remove weight from all vertex groups.

Another more usual way is to create a "tentacle base" bone and weight them to it.

Remember that even a very little weight, if it's not "counterbalanced" by a bigger weight, will have a great influence to the vertex, so you can't trust the blue color in weight paint mode only.

[image]

Comment: Awesome Josh that worked! Don't know how to mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: Just click on the up arrow on the left of the answer!

Comment: I'm having another problem I'm really strugglin with and have looked all over for an answer. I have 8 tentacles as separate objects each with their own separate animated bendy bone armature. I want to join all of the armatures into 1 but when I do ctrl-j only one of the tentacles will move afterwards and the rest of the bones are frozen when I press play. Is there a way to join the armatures into one while keeping the animations? Each armature has its own action in the action editor. I've tried for hours to use the same action for all the bones but it doesn't work. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Probably when you joined the armatures there were some bones with the same name: in this case Blender adds some suffixes (.001, .002, .003, .....). But if the bone has a different name from its corresponding vertex group it doesn't work: so rename all bones with an unique name before joining. If you do it in Pose mode with its action and with the tentacle parented, the vertex groups will be automatically renamed.

Comment: I made sure to name all of the bones uniquely from the beginning though.. Also, I'm not sure what you mean about joining in pose mode, When I select all of the armatures and go into pose mode and do ctrl-j and then go back to object mode they're still not merged into one armature.

Comment: I was talking about renaming, joining is in object mode, of course.

Comment: After joining, check why are the tentacles not moving: choose one bone, check if it has animation data, if it has the same name of the vertex group, if it moves or not .... until you'll find the problem. Or make another question and upload the file.